# Is there an easy way to manage WhatsApp images?

Tags: images, whatsapp

I'm looking for an easy way to go through my WhatsApp images to delete the ones I don't want to keep (mostly stickers, memes, other generated images).

Is there a way to do this? Preferably on desktop. I can just open the directory on Android and select and delete, but that isn't what I would consider easy due to the scrolling and the finicky way of selecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect your device via USB to a computer, you can find the data in `WhatsApp/Media/...`. (see [whatsapp faq](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/finding-media-files/?lang=en))

First you need to check whether you're using the internal storage or and sd card to store the data and select the corresponding storage when connecting via USB. You can then proceed to delete pictures from there.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I'll give that a try.